# Disable Java version with script

Tags: java, version

Due to compatibility issues i need to disable earlier version of java (without uninstalling them).
The Java control panel screen provides this feature (see screen [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/jcp/images/java-runtime-settings-3.gif)), but since it has to be done on many machines i need it to be automated.

Is there anyway to edit a config file or execute certain commands to disable dated Java versions and just leave the newest one enabled?

Comment: Why don't you point to the path of your specific Java version instead?

Comment: Are your many client computers Windows or -ix machines?